# Google Street View API V3 - tiles loaded event?

Tags: events, google-maps, google-street-view

Is there an event that fires when the Street View has finished loading all the tiles that make up a panorama? Currently if you change the position manually (`StreetViewPanorama.setPosition`) the transition is rough, and there is no way to tell when the new files have all loaded. As a result, it's not possible to display a loading GIF unless it's given an arbitrary timeout such as 2 or 3 seconds.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see all available events for a panorama here: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#StreetViewPanorama

Have you tried using the position_changed event?

Comment: yeah I've tried these. There is a JSON call to Google when the position changes to get the panorama data, including all the URL's of the tiles that make up the 360. There are events that apply when this JSON returns (such as links_changed or pano_changed) but nothing that applies when the browser has finished downloading all the tile images. I've tried adding a $.ready and $.load to the container of the street view but still no luck..

Comment: As it stands, there's no current event triggered when the tile images have loaded.

Comment: Trying to find some felicitous event as well.

There are images not single image most likely, and yep it's weird such a big provider has such weak API. Have many times stumble on such problems when you can't do something obvious with google APIs

Though the good idea is to use static image obtained from that streetview (if it's affordable)