# GoogleMapAPIv3 Streetview Loaded Event

Tags: events, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, loader, preloader

im creating a website and am using a streetview panorama on it. Now some of my target users may not have the fastest internet available so what i want to do is display a pretty loading screen while the panorama fully loads. however i couldnt find any events that fire once a streetview panorama loads.

Is there one? or if not, how would i create a faux event that fires when a panorama is fully loaded

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150891/google-street-view-api-v3-tiles-loaded-event) the StreetView SDK doesn't fire any event when the street view is finished loading.

Answer (score 0):

I do it and it works like a charm.
There is actually one way to achieve "loaded" event by using the Streetview service like this:

```
// Handle loaded-like event
var sv = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
sv.getPanorama({location: camera.eye, radius: 50}, function (data, status) {
    if (status !== 'OK') {
        console.log(`Streetview processSVData status = ${status}`);
        return;
    }
    alert(`Streetview loaded! — processSVData status = ${status}`);
}
```

Comment: getPanorama() searches for a streetview pano's. It doesn't fire when the image tiles have completely loaded in the panorama object itself.